# How can i change the server of a Tor relay

Tags: server, server-administration

I have a question about my tor relay.

I have been some months using it and now I want to change the server I use to host it, but I don't want to start again by 0, I want to maintain the relay I have.

How can I do it?

I want to do this because now I have a high traffic

Answer (score 1):

you must migrate your whole `DataDirectory` - the one you've specified in your `torrc`. after that you're pointing your new-hosted Tor to the same directory and config - and that's it! You can change a filesystem path of the dir, of course - just don't forget to reflect it in your torrc *before* running tor.

Comment: Just by copying this into the new server its ok. ORPort 9001
Nickname MyServer
ContactInfo relay@sigaint.org (Ask for PGP)
ExitPolicy reject *:*

Comment: @JaviB but the keys are better be preserved too